# Compute pairwise differences between two vectors in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two vectors and I would like to construct a matrix of their pairwise differences. Currently I do this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
b = np.array([3,2,1])
M = a.reshape((-1,1)) - b.reshape((1,-1))
```

This certainly works, but I wonder if it's really the intended way of doing things. The readability of the line is suboptimal; one has to think a while what the `reshape`s are doing. Can this be improved? Is there another "cleaner" way of achieving the same?

Comment: Maybe ask this at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as it may dangerously lead to an opinion base question.

Comment: although you can use `outer` to subtract, you can also use `M=a-b[:,None]` if it makes it more readable.

Comment: @Ehsan this gives `M.T` instead of `M`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an efficient way to do this that doesn't require you to manually reshape, using `numpy`'s [`ufunc` (universal function)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#methods) features. Each `ufunc`, including `np.subtract`, has a method called `outer`, which does what you want. ([documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html))

`outer` applies the computation (in this case, `np.subtract`) to all pairs.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> b = np.array([3,2,1])
>>> M = np.subtract.outer(a, b)
>>> M
array([[-2, -1,  0],
       [-1,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 1,  2,  3]])
>>>
```

Let's confirm that it matches your intended result.

```
>>> # This is how `M` was defined in the question:
>>> M = a.reshape((-1,1)) - b.reshape((1,-1))
>>> M
array([[-2, -1,  0],
       [-1,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 1,  2,  3]])
```

Comment: Lovely, thanks! I really didn't know about this but I was suspecting there should be a better solution. So much more readable. Great!